# Django DetailView and get request

Tags: django, django-views

I have a detail view with a drop-down list.  The user can choose an item in the drop-down list and the information about that item should appear below it.  This requires that the DetailView includes something like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(InvoiceDetail, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
    request = self.request

    if request.GET:
        try:
            invoice_selector = request.GET.get('invoice_selector', None)
            invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id = int(invoice_selector) ) # either a string representing a number or 'add invoice'
            context_object_model = invoice
        except ValueError:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounting:add_invoice'))

    return context
```

How do I over-write the context_object_model? The above code does not make the change.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you should do in `get_context_data`. You should check for "add invoice" in the `get` method, and do the rest in `get_object`.

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.invoice_selector = request.GET.get('invoice_selector')
        if self.invoice_selector = 'add invoice':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounting:add_invoice'))
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        if self.invoice_selector:
            obj = self.model.objects.get(pk=self.invoice_selector)
        else:
            obj = super().get_object()

        return obj
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It did lead me down the right path. But, it needed some modification for it to work perfectly. I edited your answer.